# Get details of current Azure VM from inside the VM using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, virtual-machines, windows-server-2016

Suppose I have a Virtual Machine provisioned in Azure running Windows Server 2016 standard Azure image.

Without installing anything onto the VM, how can I retrieve the details of the current VM using PowerShell from inside the VM?

Some properties I would like to retrieve are:

- VM name
- VM IP address
- Subscription ID
- VM location

I believe this is possible because the Windows Desktop image in Azure automatically shows most of the above information.  So how can I get this information programmatically through PowerShell?

(As usual, Microsoft documentation live up to their reputation of no value)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to use either [Azure Instance Metadata Service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service)

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{"Metadata"="true"} -Method GET -NoProxy -Uri http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2020-09-01 | ConvertTo-Json
```

---

```
{
    "compute": {
        "azEnvironment": "AZUREPUBLICCLOUD",
        "isHostCompatibilityLayerVm": "true",
        "licenseType":  "Windows_Client",
        "location": "westus",
        "name": "examplevmname",
        "offer": "Windows",
        "osProfile": {
            "adminUsername": "admin",
            "computerName": "examplevmname",
            "disablePasswordAuthentication": "true"
        },
        "osType": "linux",
        "placementGroupId": "f67c14ab-e92c-408c-ae2d-da15866ec79a",
        "plan": {
            "name": "planName",
            "product": "planProduct",
            "publisher": "planPublisher"
        },
        "platformFaultDomain": "36",
        "platformUpdateDomain": "42",
        "publicKeys": [{
                "keyData": "ssh-rsa 0",
                "path": "/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys0"
            },
            {
                "keyData": "ssh-rsa 1",
                "path": "/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys1"
            }
        ],
        "publisher": "RDFE-Test-Microsoft-Windows-Server-Group",
        "resourceGroupName": "macikgo-test-may-23",
        "resourceId": "/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/macikgo-test-may-23/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/examplevmname",
        "securityProfile": {
            "secureBootEnabled": "true",
            "virtualTpmEnabled": "false"
        },
        "sku": "Windows-Server-2012-R2-Datacenter",
        "storageProfile": {
            "dataDisks": [{
                "caching": "None",
                "createOption": "Empty",
                "diskSizeGB": "1024",
                "image": {
                    "uri": ""
                },
                "lun": "0",
                "managedDisk": {
                    "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/macikgo-test-may-23/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/exampledatadiskname",
                    "storageAccountType": "Standard_LRS"
                },
                "name": "exampledatadiskname",
                "vhd": {
                    "uri": ""
                },
                "writeAcceleratorEnabled": "false"
            }],
            "imageReference": {
                "id": "",
                "offer": "UbuntuServer",
                "publisher": "Canonical",
                "sku": "16.04.0-LTS",
                "version": "latest"
            },
            "osDisk": {
                "caching": "ReadWrite",
                "createOption": "FromImage",
                "diskSizeGB": "30",
                "diffDiskSettings": {
                    "option": "Local"
                },
                "encryptionSettings": {
                    "enabled": "false"
                },
                "image": {
                    "uri": ""
                },
                "managedDisk": {
                    "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/macikgo-test-may-23/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/exampleosdiskname",
                    "storageAccountType": "Standard_LRS"
                },
                "name": "exampleosdiskname",
                "osType": "Linux",
                "vhd": {
                    "uri": ""
                },
                "writeAcceleratorEnabled": "false"
            }
        },
        "subscriptionId": "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "tags": "baz:bash;foo:bar",
        "version": "15.05.22",
        "vmId": "02aab8a4-74ef-476e-8182-f6d2ba4166a6",
        "vmScaleSetName": "crpteste9vflji9",
        "vmSize": "Standard_A3",
        "zone": ""
    },
    "network": {
        "interface": [{
            "ipv4": {
               "ipAddress": [{
                    "privateIpAddress": "10.144.133.132",
                    "publicIpAddress": ""
                }],
                "subnet": [{
                    "address": "10.144.133.128",
                    "prefix": "26"
                }]
            },
            "ipv6": {
                "ipAddress": [
                 ]
            },
            "macAddress": "0011AAFFBB22"
        }]
    }
}
```

or [Resource Graph](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/concepts/explore-resources)

```
Search-AzGraph -Query "Resources | where type =~ 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines' | limit 1" | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
```

---

```
[
  {
    "id": "/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/ContosoVM1",
    "kind": "",
    "location": "westus2",
    "managedBy": "",
    "name": "ContosoVM1",
    "plan": {},
    "properties": {
      "hardwareProfile": {
        "vmSize": "Standard_B2s"
      },
      "networkProfile": {
        "networkInterfaces": [
          {
            "id": "/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/contosovm1535",
            "resourceGroup": "MyResourceGroup"
          }
        ]
      },
      "osProfile": {
        "adminUsername": "localAdmin",
        "computerName": "ContosoVM1",
        "secrets": [],
        "windowsConfiguration": {
          "enableAutomaticUpdates": true,
          "provisionVMAgent": true
        }
      },
      "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
      "storageProfile": {
        "dataDisks": [],
        "imageReference": {
          "offer": "WindowsServer",
          "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
          "sku": "2016-Datacenter",
          "version": "latest"
        },
        "osDisk": {
          "caching": "ReadWrite",
          "createOption": "FromImage",
          "diskSizeGB": 127,
          "managedDisk": {
            "id": "/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/ContosoVM1_OsDisk_1_9676b7e1b3c44e2cb672338ebe6f5166",
            "resourceGroup": "MyResourceGroup",
            "storageAccountType": "Premium_LRS"
          },
          "name": "ContosoVM1_OsDisk_1_9676b7e1b3c44e2cb672338ebe6f5166",
          "osType": "Windows"
        }
      },
      "vmId": "bbb9b451-6dc7-4117-bec5-c971eb1118c6"
    },
    "resourceGroup": "MyResourceGroup",
    "sku": {},
    "subscriptionId": "<subscriptionId>",
    "tags": {},
    "type": "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines"
  }
]
```

Run PowerShell scripts in your Windows VM by using Run Command, [more detail here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command)

```
az vm run-command invoke  --command-id RunPowerShellScript --name win-vm -g my-resource-group \
    --scripts @script.ps1 --parameters "arg1=somefoo" "arg2=somebar"
```